# How does quadratic programming solve the Support Vector Machine problem?

Tags: optimization, svm, constrained-optimization

I have just been reading that Quadratic Programming can be used to solve the Support Vector Machine optimization.

My solver can minimize this typ of problem

$$\text{J}_{min} = \frac{1}{2}x^TQx + c^Tx$$
Where it subject to:
$$Ax \leq b$$
$$x \geq 0$$

All I need to do is to create the $Q, A$ matrices and $b, c$ vectors.
Assume that we have our data and the labels. Notice that this example is for two classes only. One class have the label $1$ and the other has the label $-1$.

```
X = [1, 2; 2, 3; 3, 3; 2, 1; 3, 2];
labels = [-1; -1; 1; 1; 1];
```

And we are using a polynomial kernel with the second degree

```
K = @(x1,x2) (1 + x1*x2').^2;
```

And then I create my symmetric $Q$ matrix

```
m = size(X, 1);
Q = zeros(m,m);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:m
        Q(i,j) = labels(i)*labels(j)*K(X(i,:), X(j,:));
    end
end
```

The objective function $c$ is simple just $-1$ as a vector

```
c = -ones(m, 1);
```

And the constaints are a matrix $A$ and the vector $b$

```
A = labels';
b = 0;
```

Now I can solve this optimization problem by using [quadprog](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/Optimization/quadprog.c). See both MATLAB-code and C-code.

```
[x, solution] = quadprog(Q, c, A, b)
```

And the solution $x$ was:

```
0.36538
1.4423
2.6154
2.1346
-2.9423
```

Or for the lazy one who have GNU Octave's internal QP-solver. This will give the same results of $x$.

```
[x, ~, e] = qp([], Q, c, [], [], [], [], [], A, b)
```

**Question:**

What does $x$ mean here? How should I use $x$ now?
Is $x$ quadratic boundaries?